# How to multithread a for loop?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

In JavaScript if I need a for loop multithreaded, what is the simplest possible way to do this (browser or node)?

So that

```
For x in 5: print (x)
```

Would run each for loop pass in parrelell. It doesn't matter if they happen in order.

Is this possible to do simply?
Is this even a thing?

Comment: I guess "worker" threads may be an option - but that code you've posted isn't even javascript, so ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded due to its event-driven and non-blocking I/O nature. You can't achieve true multi-threading directly.
Though, you can achieve concurrent execution using technique like [`Web Workers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) in the browser.
This will not give you true multi-threading, but can help you run code concurrently in separate threads.

Here's an example of how you can achieve that using Web Workers in a browser environment:

**Script in HTML:**

```
<body>
  <script>
    //create multiple web workers
    const numWorkers = 5;
    const workers = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
        workers.push(worker);

        worker.postMessage(i); //send data to the worker
    }

    //listen to messages from workers
    workers.forEach((worker, index) => {
        worker.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log(`Worker ${index} returned: ${event.data}`);
        };
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Create the worker script that does the work:

```
//worker.js
self.onmessage = function(event) {
  let x = event.data;

  //perform some work here
  let result = `Result for ${x}`;

  //send the result back to the main thread
  self.postMessage(result);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs in a single line, one thing at a time. If you want to do a "for loop" in multiple lines at once, you can use something called Web Workers in browsers or worker_threads in Node.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).